# Regression in R for only certain rows in a table

Tags: r, regression

If I am running a linear regression in R, how can I set parameters for which rows of my dataset to use in the regression?

```
Sample_table
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4
2    5    2    4
2    5    4    2
5    8    9    2
```

I want `lm(A ~ B + C)` but only when D = 4. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lm(A ~ B + C, data = Sample_table, subset = D == 4)
```